# infinitive or gerund: two most important keys to succeed

Tags: definite-article, infinitive-vs-gerund, collocations

In the following sentence, should "two" be preceded by "the"? And is "succeed" correct?

> Diligence and intelligence are two most important keys to succeed.

Comment: Yes, "the" should be added, and "succeed"  is correct, although it'll be better if you add the object in which one is succeeding (e.g "in life")

Comment: Most people would say "key to" is followed by a noun or gerund.

Comment: It's better to use "key to succeed in life" or "key to success"

Comment: Although *succeed* isn't completely wrong, it would be more natural to use *success*: *keys to* ***success***. If keeping *succeed*, something like *keys **needed** to succeed* would sound better.